# Format date in mongodb query output on shell

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, datetime-format

I want to format the date time into an specific format on the mongo shell output

My query

```
db.getCollection('people').find({
        date: { 
            $gte: ISODate("2017-04-24T14:04:34.447Z") 
        }
    },
    {
        _id: 0,
        age: 0,

    }
);
```

My output against this query:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "user_id" : "bcd020",
    "status" : "D",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-04-24T14:04:34.447Z")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "user_id" : "bcd021",
    "status" : "D",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-04-24T14:04:34.447Z")
}
```

What i want is to format the datetime in the output something like,

```
/* 1 */
    {
        "user_id" : "bcd020",
        "status" : "D",
        "date" : 2017-04-24 14:04:34
    }

    /* 2 */
    {
        "user_id" : "bcd021",
        "status" : "D",
        "date" : 2017-04-24 14:04:34
    }
```

Comment: Use `{
   $project: {
    date: {
     $dateToString: {
      format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
      date: "$date"
     }
    }
   }
 }` in aggregation pipeline

Comment: yes i saw this too in mongo docs, so its not possible with out aggregation?

Comment: I doubt it. You may just get documents, iterate and use javascipt to format the date.

Comment: ok thank veeram, put an answer if possible for you, the javascript way.

Comment: Np. `ISODate` i s just a wrapper over javascript date. So you should be able to do everything that you do on regular date object. See if this helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solution is using aggregation pipeline as stated by **Veeram** in comments section

```
db.getCollection('people').aggregate([
    {
        $project:{
            datetime: {$dateToString: {format: "%G-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",date: "$datetime"}},
            age : 1
        }
    }
]);
```