# Format Date() for express-handlebars

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express-handlebars

I want to display the date in the format "YYYY MM DD".

I have tried with expresss-handlebars code, {{this.createdAt.toDateString()}}

DB/Post.js

```
username: String,
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: new Date()
    }
```

index.js

```
app.get('/', async (req, res)=>{
    const posts = await Post.find().sort({"createdAt": -1})
    res.render('index', {
        posts
    });
})
```

post.handlebars

```
{{this.createdAt.toDateString()}}
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43591405/format-date-in-mongodb-query-output-on-shell

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
{{this.createdAt.toLocaleDateString('EU'))}};
```

this will return YYYY-MM-DD, if you want to drop the `-` add split and join:

`{{this.createdAt.toLocaleDateString('EU')).split('-').join(' ')}};`

Comment: It gives an error "Parse error", "Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID' "

Comment: you have an error somwhere else, if u want edit and post all relevant code, run: `let new_date = new Date();
console.log(new_date.toLocaleDateString('EU'));` and see.